# USB 3.0 flash drive not being detected

Tags: drivers, usb, usb-drive

I've looked around at numerous other questions about this topic, but none of them seems to help for me.

I have just bought a new 64Gb SanDisk USB 3.0 flash drive. The device works perfectly on Windows but will not work on my Ubuntu 18.04.3 system.

Other older USB flash drives (non 3.0) work perfectly. This is the dmesg output from a working flash drive:

```
[ 3294.711026] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 3294.862173] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000
[ 3294.862176] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3294.862178] usb 3-3: Product: USB DISK
[ 3294.862179] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: SMI Corporation
[ 3294.862180] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: AA04012700057951
[ 3294.862718] usb-storage 3-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3294.862854] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-3:1.0
[ 3295.892365] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     S31B0711 USB DISK         1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 3295.893023] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 3295.894369] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 506880 512-byte logical blocks: (260 MB/248 MiB)
[ 3295.895065] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 3295.895070] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 3295.895637] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 3295.895646] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3295.949633]  sdb: sdb1
[ 3295.951686] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

And this is what I get with the non-working drive:

```
[ 4767.506296] usb 4-3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 4767.527455] usb 4-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5581
[ 4767.527458] usb 4-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4767.527459] usb 4-3: Product: Ultra
[ 4767.527460] usb 4-3: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 4767.527461] usb 4-3: SerialNumber: 01012f36747c0129815ea130fa9a0aace2c965df046c8184e88d20ee76887fdaed1600000000000000000000d1dc4ec9ff1628008155810794a6f969
[ 4767.528394] usb-storage 4-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 4767.528611] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-3:1.0
[ 4768.670675] usb 4-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 4768.834621] usb 4-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 4768.998668] usb 4-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 4769.162620] usb 4-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
```

lsusb correctly shows the device as present (see the "SanDisk Corp. Ultra" line):

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0781:5581 SanDisk Corp. Ultra
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f2:b35a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But running `fdisk -l` does not show the drive.

Googling the error "reset SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd" seems to suggest some low-level communication with the USB device has failed. But I have yet to find a workable solution.

I'm now out of ideas so I'm looking for possible suggestions!

Edit:

I am plugging the drive into a Blue USB socket.

Requested information:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" && sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Moth"
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
       description: Motherboard
       product: W65_67SZ
       vendor: Notebook
       physical id: 0
       version: Not Applicable
       serial: Not Applicable
```

Comment: Is this a dual-boot system? If so, can you test the device on another Linux system?

Comment: @Matt Caswell 1) Are you plugging the USB3 drive into a red socket, a blue socket, a white socket, or a yellow socket? 2) Please run in Ubuntu `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" && sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Moth"' 3) Please click [edit] and put your answers to 1 and 2 in the question. Please don't use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].

Comment: Question updated with the requested information.This is not a dual boot system